# Is it possible to stream flash viewport (stage?) to flash media streaming server?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, netstream

I want to live stream two video cameras as one twice bigger video stream to flash media streaming server. I'm at the point where I have two video objects on a stage showing pictures from two webcams.

I am reading documentation of NetStream class but I couldn't find a way to stream both video objects as one stream.

I would like to get some pointers as to how could I tackle that problem.

Comment: I don't think you can put two videos on the same stream from Flash. Why wouldn't you use two streams and merge the videos on the server?

Comment: Wouldn't there be a sync issue? Can I synchronize both of the streams on the server if it's a live stream? (videos should be displayed one below another)

Comment: well... I'm not sure, you may have a little offset between the two videos, but since it's the same server and same connection I doubt it will be noticable...

Answer (score 0):

You could dive into the BitmapData object-- but be prepared for some interesting math and draw() methods. You will likely want to start a new canvas/window to hold your new composite image- then NetStream that to your media server.

There might be an easier way than BitmapData would provide you (since I modify my stream a LOT, it's the one I've come to know).

Check this out: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000796.html

Please do keep us updated because this would be an exquisite code example!